# SQL - select column value of previous matching row

Tags: sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

[image: 1]

I have a dataset like the above. Basically it's like a website session which I have a start + end activity, and in between there could be other unrelated records.

I need to pull the records based on:

- I need to report all the "end" activity from the table
- In each "end" record, I need to find its nearest previous "start" row's "Content_ID" value. The record must also match the "Profile_ID" as well
- The result I expected is as follows:

[image]

May I ask how could I construct the SQL to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: MySQL or BigQuery? Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below in BigQuery.

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(Content_ID),
       LAST_VALUE(IF(Activity = 'start', Content_ID, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS Content_ID
  FROM sample_table
QUALIFY Activity = 'end'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Profile_ID ORDER BY Created_Time);
```

###### Query results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can address this as a gaps-and-island problem, where an island begins every time an activity `start`s for a given `profile_id`: we can define the groups with a window sum.

Then, for every end activity, we need to report the content id of the beginning of the island.

```
select profile_id, created_time,
    max(case when activity = 'start' then content_id end) 
        over(partition by profile_id, grp) content_id
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when activity = 'start' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by profile_id order by created_time) grp
    from mytable t
) t
where activity = 'end'
```

Depending on the database you actually use (BQ or MySQL), some syntax shortcuts exists to shorten the conditional expressions. In BQ for example, we would phrase the window sum with `countif`:

```
countif(activity = 'start') 
    over(partition by profile_id order by created_time) grp
```